# Android ChildFragmentManager().findFragmentById() always null

Tags: android, android-fragments, child-fragment

I stumbled into a crazy little 'bug', or i'm just doing something wrong. I am trying to get the reference to a fragment that is inside a fragment. So we have `ParentFragment`, that is a child of `MainActivity`. I can get a reference to this ParentFragment without a problem, because the `ParentFragment` is added to the `MainActivity` via code:

```
ParentFragment fragment = new ParentFragment();

FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

transaction.replace(R.id.fragmentPlaceholder, fragment);
transaction.commit();
```

I have added a `ChildFragment` to the `ParentFragment` via XML like this:

*parent_fragment.xml*

```
<RelativeLayout ... etc>
    .. some other views, findViewById('') works great on these.
    <fragment
        android:layout_width="70dp"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:id="@+id/childFragment1"
        android:tag="1"
        class="com.my.package.ChildFragment"
        android:name="com.my.package.ChildFragment"
        tools:layout="@layout/child_fragment" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

All works fine, the ChildFragment(s) show up in the ParentFragment. The only thing is; i cannot find the fragmentById.

I have tried multiple ways of achieving this, how it should be done (?) :

```
getChildFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.childFragment1)
```

Didn't work. Also, getting the Activity and using that fragment manager doesn't work (.. of course).

I have also tried getting all fragments in the ChildFragmentManager, iterating over them etc. But this always returns null:

```
getChildFragmentManager().getFragments()
```

Do you have any idea why this is happening? Can't i use the ChildFragrentManager if the fragments are not added via code?

Thanks!

Comment: I think you should try to find them using their `Tag` instead.

Comment: Tested it, and doesn't make a difference, note that `getChildFragmentManager().getFragments()` also returns null.

Comment: oh. I haven't really used child fragments before, but isn't there a method something like `getSupportChildFragmentManager()`? Considering these seem to be support fragments, if that exists, that's the one  that has it.

Comment: No only getChildFragmentManager.. Let me try to make everything regular fragments instead of support fragments

Comment: Method getChildFragmentManager of support fragment returns support fragment manager. Support fragments naturally do not support native child fragments.

Comment: Yes, that's it. I had to strip any reference of FragmentActivity and the supportFragmentManagers etc. Now it works like a charm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use nested Fragments and be able to get a reference to them via findFragmentById you cannot use the support package.

I changed all `getSupportFragmentManager()`'s to `getFragmentManager()` and replaced all `FragmentActivity`'s with regular `Activity`'s.

Now it works as expected, just call `getChildFragmentManager().findFragmentById()`.

Comment: Please note the answer of Marcin Jędrzejewski, some strange behaviours might appear.

Answer (score 5):

You must add your child fragment dynamically. See [here](http://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-4.2.html#NestedFragments):

> Note: You cannot inflate a layout into a fragment when that layout
>   includes a <fragment>. Nested fragments are only supported when added
>   to a fragment dynamically.

ps. if you are planning to use nested fragments then be prepared for various strange behaviours, you can find them in bug reports to android platform:

https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/list?can=2&q=nested+fragment&sort=-opened&colspec=ID+Status+Priority+Owner+Summary+Stars+Reporter+Opened&cells=tiles

Comment: This isn't a must, as long as you don't use the support classes.

Comment: @ErikTerwan there are also issues with non-support nested fragments (or maybe they fixed them lately), you can read on it here: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=58906&q=nested%20fragment&sort=-opened&colspec=ID%20Status%20Priority%20Owner%20Summary%20Stars%20Reporter%20Opened

Comment: Yeah the thing about ChildFragments still existing is not something i am noticing, after removing the ParentFragment and adding it again, all is good. The fragments are recreated like they should. So i guess they fixed that issue..?

Comment: Probably, the problem with using native fragment support is that if you run it on older devices then those fixes will (probably) be not applied, so you would have to always test your code on all supported API versions. With support library its easy - support library is always inside your APK